# how to stop thread for a particular condition in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am testing on a site which has multiple options.

**For example, **

> let's say on the home page (1st sampler) we have two options Option A
>   and Option B. So if I choose option it will navigate to another page
>   (2nd sampler) and show me some results regarding option A and from
>   those results I will click on any of the results and go to the next
>   page (3rd sampler).

But when I click on Option B on the home page (1st sampler), there is no result to show me (in the 2nd sampler) so I don't want it to navigate and execute the 3rd sampler.

I want to stop the execution if there is no result coming in the result page of option B. How should I implement this in JMeter.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this, you will need to add [Beanshell post-processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) on your *Option B* with the following code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService;

String prevResult = JMeterContextService.getContext()
                        .getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString();

if(prevResult == null || prevResult.isEmpty()) // | ---> ||
      JMeterContextService.getContext().getThread().stop();
```

This will check previous response and if its empty stop current thread. If response is not empty, test execution will continue.

Comment: Actually the options are getting appended withing the next request which will be generated after i click any of them.There is no different sampler for different option.So where should I put this BeanShell post processor?

Comment: You wrote in your question that 2nd sampler will navigate to another page and that you wanna have valid response there, so you should add the post processor on it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using

- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
- [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie)
- and [Test Action Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action)

combination like:

[image: Test Action Sampler]